# EPSON imagescan v3 doesn't recognize my scanner through WiFi

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, scanner, canon

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and EPSON <s>L3150</s>L3156. It is connected through WiFi. The printer/scanner works perfectly on Windows, but I can't figure out how to use it on Ubuntu.

From [here,](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) I installed "ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)" Printer Driver, and from [here,](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php) I installed Imagescan v3. But Imagescan v3 doesn't recognize the scanner. When I execute `imagescan --no-interface`, it says "no usable devices available".

The [manual](http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/imagescanv3_e.html) says I have to set the IP Address, so I executed the following command:

```
CUPS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 /usr/lib/cups/backend/snmp 2>&1 | tee snmp.log
```

to identify the IP Address. It said the URI is `lpd://192.168.35.251:515/PASSTHRU`, and I edited `/etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf` accordingly:

```
[device]

net.udi    = networkscan:esci://192.168.35.251:1865
net.vendor = Epson
net.model  = DS-5500
```

But Imagescan v3 still doesn't recognize the scanner. Why?

**EDIT:** It turns out my printer/scanner is not L3150, but L3156. [This page](https://www.epson.co.kr/%EA%B3%A0%EA%B0%9D%EC%A7%80%EC%9B%90/%ED%94%84%EB%A6%B0%ED%84%B0/%EB%B3%B5%ED%95%A9%EA%B8%B0/%EC%A0%95%ED%92%88%EB%AC%B4%ED%95%9C-L-%EC%8B%9C%EB%A6%AC%EC%A6%88/Epson-%EC%99%84%EC%84%B1%ED%98%95-%EA%B0%80%EC%A0%95%EC%9A%A9-%EB%B3%B5%ED%95%A9%EA%B8%B0-L3156/s/SPT_C11CG86512#drivers) doesn't show the driver for Linux. Does that mean EPSON doesn't officially support L3156 on Ubuntu?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1487133/14650 for a solution working for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. And cross your fingers that your device is still supported.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you figured this out already, but I think you have the syntax wrong. The first line should be:

myscanner.udi    = esci:networkscan://192.168.1.123

You have the prefixes backwards. I don't think you need the port number unless it was changed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, though using Debian 10. I looked into the `imagescan.conf` file. It seems that the manual contains a simple typo. In the file, the title of the section (or whatever it's called) is:

```
[devices]
```

and not `[device]`. When I inserted the scanner's data under `[devices]`, it worked.

(But still, the previous answer about syntax error stands. I used the syntax as in the manual, so opposite to what you originally posted).