# Installing Epson Iscan For Linux

Tags: drivers, scanner

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad. I have an Epson Perfection 1240u Photo scanner with a backlit film adaptor and I want to get it running. I've downloaded the software recommended by Epson (iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb) and extracted the files which are sitting in my downloads folder. I've tried running sudo ./install.sh, as per the instructions here:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/iscan_e.html#sec6-1

and here:

https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/12/09/how-to-install-epson-scanner-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-lts/

but all I get is 'command not found'. Could someone please explain to me - in the simplest terms possible please as I'm a complete novice and therefore don't understand most of the terminology - what I need to do to install this software?

Comment: If you downloaded the `.deb` file, you have to run `sudo dpkg --install iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb` (without extracting the file) from the folder where the file is located

Comment: Not really in this case. )) I am writing an answer.

Comment: You are right, @Pilot6 . However fancy way to name folders :)

Answer (score 2):

You've downloaded `iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz` file.

It is an archive that contains `iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb` directory.

Extract that directory to your Home folder.

Then run in a terminal

```
cd iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: OK; I just did what you suggested Pilot6 and  stuff actually happened. The terminal has now finished, leaving this:   'hugh@hugh-ThinkPad-E14:~/iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb$'       should I now type in another command?

Comment: If you've run both commands, then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

EPSON's iscan software and plugins used to work for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, but EPSON seems to have consolidated (read: "broken") the older efforts.

As of today, to make the scanner work you might be able to find the (non-free) scanner plugin for download on the EPSON website.

1. Go to the [EPSON Download Center website](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) (in doubt, search the Web as the URL seems to change).
2. Search for your printer/scanner/MFP model and select "Linux" for Operating System.
3. Download the scanner driver archive (e.g. "Epson Scan 2") from the result page.
4. Unzip the downloaded `.tar.gz` file (e.g. `tar xfz ...`) and `cd` into the created folder with the same name as the downloaded file.
5. You'll find a `core/` and a `plugins/` folder that both include a `.deb` file you can install. The EPSON scan program is in the core folder (it doesn't detect the printer over the network for me, so of no use), for the GNOME Document Scanner you only need the Debian package in the plugins folder, e.g.

```
dpkg -i plugins/epsonscan2-non-free-plugin_1.0.0.6-1_amd64.deb
```

**Note:** If you prefer not to work in the terminal you should be able to use GNOME's file manager to find and extract the `plugins/*.deb` file inside the `.tar.gz` archive, and install it with the GNOME Software Center.

I can confirm this works for my EPSON WF-7710 MFP scanner to scan over the network. GNOME's Document Scanner shows two entries of detected scanners, though. The one shipped with Ubuntu ("Epson WF-7710 Series") makes the scanner time out, while the installed one ("eSCL EPSON WF-7710 Series") scans successfully.

*P.S.: This information is [taken from the TutorialForLinux website](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2023/02/04/how-to-download-epson-image-scan-software-for-ubuntu-22-04/), originally.*
*PPS: If you like Ansible you can use the `painless.software` [Ansible role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/painless/software) to install the driver ([source code](https://github.com/painless-software/ansible-role-software/blob/main/tasks/base/printers.yml)).*