# Ubuntu scanner software for Epson

Tags: scanner, epson

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.6. I have an Epson "V600" scanner.

Following the directions here, I have managed to load software that controls it to scan reflective media - namely prints - using "SimpleScan" software and having "SimpleScan" control the scanner, but not to use the software packaged with the scanner to control it; scanning slides and negatives was my primary reason for purchasing it. My wife's Windows computer allows me to scan any media I want to, but both of us are very tired of my borrowing her computer to do that.

Am I missing a simple step that would allow my Ubuntu box to control the scanner??

Comment: Perhaps I’m misunderstanding something: you *can* or you *cannot* use the scanner with Ubuntu? Is the goal to use the Windows-based software on Ubuntu to use all the features of the scanner? 

Comment: Simple? No. You *might* be able to get the Epson software to work with Wine (you might not -- I've not tried it), but that software cannot control the USB ports or other peripheral interfaces necessary to operate the scanner. Wine won't do that.

Comment: If you have an Epson Perfection V600 Photo, then this driver may be suitable https://epson.com/Support/Scanners/Perfection-Series/Epson-Perfection-V600-Photo/s/SPT_B11B198011?review-filter=Linux  Perfection V600 photo compatible with  http://support.epson.net/linux/en/epsonscan2.php

Comment: Let me clarify for people that did Not Read your post before responding:<BR>
1: The V600 is a flatbed scanner that can scan transparencies, the reason you would get this model.<BR>
2: The epsonscan2 software does not provide a way to scan transparencies.<P> The question posted is asking what software will scan transparencies on this transparency capable scanner.<P> I tried xsane (<I>I used to have great luck with it</I>) but only get core dumps on current versions of Ubuntu and Fedora.

Comment: From the same Epson download site try the package with the one withe the lower version number. For me that was 2.30.4 

The package turned out to be "iscan" and it has options for negative and slide scanning.

Comment: Did you actually run it? I downloaded it, but I'm not sure where to look for the program to run.

Answer (score 1):

Process is the same for either iscan or epsonscan.
For example I downloaded iscan-gt-x770-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz and epsonscan2-bundle-6.6.40.0.x86_64.deb.tar.gz.
In an xterm I went to my download directory.
Those are tar files that have used the gzip option.
If you want to see the what the tar command is doing you run it like this:
tar -xzvf iscan-gt-x770-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz
This will create sub directory iscan-gt-x770-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb/, change into it and if you have added your userID to sudo you can then run:
sudo ./install.sh
This works for iscan and/or epsonscan2.
Afterwards the commands should have been added to your menu and you can run them from a terminal using **epsonscan2** or **iscan** as the command.
I tested both on Fedora, no problem at all with either but iscan was more feature rich however scanning of negatives is totally manual while the epson windows package automatically scans each negative frame as an individual file.
-- TLDR --
I finally tried iscan on my Ubuntu box and it fails trying to connect to the scanner, epsonscan2 work perfectly.
I suspect I'm missing a sane package or there is a weird USP id error, the error window has the xsane logo on it.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1487133/14650 for a solution working for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It looks like the V600 model is still supported by EPSON on Linux.